# Div shifts on page refresh

Tags: html, express, innerhtml

I have an html page with just `<div id="app"></div>`, and `<script type="module" src="router.js"></script>` to load the JS files (vanilla JS web app). I'm serving it with `res.sendFile()` using Express.

I have a navbar, and then the rest of the body.  The weird thing is that if I split the navbar and body into two divs, the navbar div shifts when the page loads or refreshes.

I first load the navbar with `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = NavBar()`, and then later add the body with `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML += content`.  This works and everything loads and displays just fine, but the navbar at the top shifts right (since there's no vertical scroll bar), then left (when the scroll bar reappears).  It basically "jolts" right, then left, really fast due to the scroll bar.  The navbar includes `position: fixed` with `max-width: 1200px`.  This only happens when a vertical scroll bar exists.  Shorter pages that have no scroll bar do not have this problem.

I thought it might be a css issue, but if I load all the content at once with `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = NavBar() + content`, the navbar does not shift on page load or refresh, and that's what I want. This actually makes sense since all content is loaded and displayed at one.

The problem with that approach is that I have to do it for every page.  So, the "About" page would be loaded with `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = NavBar() + '<h1>About page</h1>';`, the "Contact" page with `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = NavBar() + '<h1>Contact page</h1>';`, and so forth.

I would rather load `NavBar()` once near the root of my application with something like `document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = NavBar()`, or even something like `document.querySelector('#navbar').innerHTML = NavBar()`, then append the body of each page later on, depending on the route.

Navbar html:

```
<div class="navbar--container">
    <div class="navbar--wrapper">
      <div class="navbar--site-header-inner">
        <div>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#search">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="logout" style="cursor: pointer">Logout</a></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Navbar css:

```
.navbar--container {
  background: linear-gradient(57deg, #00C6A7 0%, #1E4D92 100%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.navbar--wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 16px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Is it possible to append html content to existing html content without having elements "jump" on page refresh?

Comment: I would split up `nav` and `content`, so start with this: `<div id="app"> <div id="nav"></div> <div id="content"></div> </div>`, and then add your content like this: `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content`. Should solve your problem and is easier to understand, and still in 5 years when you forgot all about how you wrote this app.

Comment: The navbar still shifts, unfortunately. Maybe it's the css? I'll update my question to show the html and css.

Comment: **Sidenote:** This line `<a id="logout" style="cursor: pointer">Logout</a></li>` contains an `</li>` at the end that shouldn't be there.